# Getting Outlook.Store is extremly slow

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to bind to ItemLoad and ItemSend of all stores on the Outlook client, but it is extremely slow.

Here's my code...

```
Private Shared WithEvents _explorer As Outlook.Explorer = Nothing
Private Shared WithEvents _inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Public Shared Sub Init()
    _explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.Application.ActiveExplorer
    _inspectors = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim stores As Outlook.Stores = ns.Stores
    For i As Integer = 1 To stores.Count
        Try
            Dim store As Outlook.Store = stores(i)
            Dim sentFolder As Outlook.Folder = CType(store.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail), Outlook.Folder)
            Dim sentItem As Outlook.Items = sentFolder.Items
            AddHandler sentItem.ItemAdd, AddressOf MailSendt
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
        End Try
    Next
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(stores)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns)
End Sub
```

The line...

```
Dim store As Outlook.Store = stores(i)
```

... is extremly slow. It can take 2-4 seconds - and when my users have like 20-30 stores it can take a couple of minutes where Outlook is locked.

We're using latest version of Office 365.

Any idea how to speed it up?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to set the event handlers on all items in the profile?!

Comment: I'm trying to listen to all the users inbox and sent items, so I will get notified (with the email) when items are sent or recieved. This goes for their personal folders and shared mailboxes.

Comment: Why would you want ItemLoad and ItemSend for thousands of items?

Comment: I'm not ItemLoad or ItemSend for thousand of items - only for like 20-30 mailboxes. I'm listening on the mailboxes for new items.

Comment: So it is Application.ItemSend and Application.ItemLoad, right? Why do you need to open the stores then?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko sry for not being clear enough - my bad. I updated my sample code. I need to "catch" when a users mail is sent. So to get all mailinfo (EntryID etc), I'm watching each stores sent folder for the "ItemAdd" event ... so therefor I have to connect to each stores sent folder - and this is sloooooow.

Comment: Do you watch for items sent by other users whose mailbox the current user has open? Or only for the items sent by the current user?

Comment: I watch for their personal mailboxes and the shared mailboxes the user is in.